# Sequence of smallest numbers with a given number of divisors

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $(a(n))$ be the sequence defined by $a(n)$ is the smallest positive integer with $n$ distincts divisors.

I computed the first values: 1,2,4,6,16,12,64,24,36… but I was wondering if there was a way to estimate $a(n)$ in terms of simple functions (e.g. $a(n)\sim_{n\to \infty}e^{\alpha n}$ or something) or at least to find bounds (e.g. $\Theta$, $O$, $o$, etc.).

Comment: An upper bound is easy, $a(n) \leqslant 2^{n-1}$, and we have equality when $n$ is prime. But $a(n)$ is much smaller for composite $n$ (except the first few, where it's not _much_).

Comment: This is https://oeis.org/A005179.

Comment: I've made to myself those remarks before, but thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

These are given in [OEIS A005179](http://oeis.org/A005179).  Several formulas are given.  There is no asymptotic growth rate because for $n$ prime $a(n)=2^{n-1}$ but for $n$ highly composite it is much smaller.